# Не получается воспроизвести музыку в python через модуль pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Пробовал ещё `pyglet`, но там был только маленький писк и всё.

Как воспроизвести mp3?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код, который не работает. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Исправить ошибку бывает легче, чем написать всё сначала. Здесь принято именно помогать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подставляйте свою музыку и вперед.

```
import pygame, pygame.mixer, time
from pygame.locals import *


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()            
        self.game_start = True   
        self.window_width = 1200 
        self.window_height = 600 
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.window_width, self.window_height)) 
        self.background = pygame.image.load("img/background.jpg")             # !!!
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (self.window_width, self.window_height)) 

        ... 

        # МУЗЫКА
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.set_reserved(0)
        self.game_music = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/game_music.wav")        # <<<-------< !!!
        pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(self.game_music,-1)

        # FPS
        self.fps = pygame.time.Clock() 

        # LOOP 
        self.game_init = True
        while self.game_init:
            self.fps.tick(30) 
            for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

                ...

            self.window.blit(self.background,(0,0))    
            pygame.display.update()
Game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]